# Split and take part of string from column values and make new column from that in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a strings like this as a value of one column in my df.

```
ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-74/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232
ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-89/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232
```

How to get new column with part of this columns. Part that I need is

```
74
89
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`string.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) allows you to explode a string into a list of parts according to a separator (here `/` and `-`).

```
s = 'ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-74/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232'
print s.split('/')[2].split('-')[1]
# 74
```

Use [`pandas.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to apply it to your column

```
df['b'] = df['a'].apply(lambda s:s.split('/')[2].split('-')[1])
print (df)
```

output

```
                                              a   b
0  ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-74/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232  74
1  ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-89/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232  89
```

nb: Use [*@A-Za-z*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44885290/1545917)'s solution, it's faster than mine.

Comment: Nice one. Question: what if I further need to apply a condition? i.e.: only fill `df['b']` if `s` includes string `OPP`

Answer (score 2):

If this is the df

```
    val
0   ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-74/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232
1   ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-89/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232
```

You can use str.extract

```
df['num_val'] = df.val.str.extract('LNFFF-(\d+)/', expand = False)
```

You get

```
    val                                             num_val
0   ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-74/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232   74
1   ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-89/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232   89
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dataframe is called df and your column col :

```
 df['sub_col'] = pd.Series([s[21:23] for s in df['col'].values], index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-74/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232',
                         'ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-89/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232']})  
print (df)
                                               a
0  ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-74/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232
1  ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-89/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232

df['new'] = df['a'].str.extract('LNFFF-(\d+)', expand=False)
#if necessary convert to ints
df['new'] = df['new'].astype(int)
print (df)
                                               a new
0  ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-74/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232  74
1  ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-89/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232  89
```

Solution with splitting by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and selecting by [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
df['new'] = df['a'].str.split('/').str[2].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
print (df)
                                               a new
0  ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-74/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232  74
1  ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-89/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232  89
```

---

```
df['new'] = df['a'].str.split('/').str[2].str.split('-').str[1]
print (df)
                                               a new
0  ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-74/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232  74
1  ttt-OPP/MKKL-7/LNFFF-89/OOOP-71/AAD-1/RRR-232  89
```